# Store filtered employees in training record

Tags: ms-access

Good afternoon,
I have a form used to create a "toolbox talk". A toolbox talk is not always applicable to every employee but might be limited to a specific department, gender, or competency (or any combination of the three). I have created a subform which using unbound text boxes allows me to filter my list of employees based on the toolbox talk criteria - great!. See screenshot below:
[image]

However what I cant work out now is how I can then store the filtered results (list of employees) as recipients against the toolbox talk record.
I know that I could include a control to select employee ID/Names line by line as per the filtered results, however I was hoping that a quicker option could be created.

Can someone please suggest a possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to 'batch' create records, one approach is an INSERT SELECT action SQL that uses the same criteria selected by the form controls. If your code applies this criteria to the form Filter property, that property can be referenced to incorporate filter criteria for SQL. I prefer to use CurrentDb.Execute because then don't have to deal with RunSQL popup warnings.

```
Private Sub Command16_Click()  
Dim mySql As String          
mySql = "INSERT INTO tblEmployeeToolboxTalk (EmployeeID, ToolboxTalkID) " & _
   "SELECT EmployeeID," & Me.ToolboxTalkID & " AS TTID FROM tblEmployees WHERE " & Me.Filter      
CurrentDb.Execute mySql
End Sub
```

If you need guidance on conditionally building filter criteria in VBA, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: I have attempted this in code with no success, I get Run-time error '3134': Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Code: `Private Sub Command16_Click()

Dim mySql As String
    
    'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        
    mySql = "INSERT INTO tblEmployeeToolboxTalk (EmployeeID,ToolboxTalkID) VALUES (" & EmployeeID & "," & ToolboxTalkID & ")"

    DoCmd.RunSQL mySql
    
End Sub`

Comment: I also attempted in SQL which seemed to work but I couldnt figure out how to apply filter criteria. I think I prefer to use VBA

Comment: See revised answer.